# Convert address to multi value during migration

Tags: migrations

I have a migration that imports data into my address field and it works perfect.

```
  field_address/locality:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: city
  field_address/postal_code:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: postalcode
```

The problem I am running into is that some data from my source has multiple values in the city so I need to add some logic that if it has multiple cities, create 2 address field values (multi-value).

I was thinking to make a destination plugin. As a proof of concept I tried to edit `Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\Entity::getEntity()` with the below options but none of them worked:

```
$row->setDestinationProperty("field_address/locality", ['Chicago', 'Oakbrook']);
```

```
$row->setSourceProperty("field_address/locality", [0 => ['value' => 'Chicago'], 1 => ['value' => 'Oakbrook'], []]);
```

```
$row->setDestinationProperty("field_address/0/locality", 'Chicago');
$row->setDestinationProperty("field_address/1/locality", 'Oakbrook');
```

Comment: A destination plugin is wrong for this, because they create entities, not fields. You have to use process plugins for this, like `explode` or `sub_process` (or most likely a chain of them). See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins

Comment: The thing is the address field is an entity that has multiple fields. So `field_address/locality` and `field_address/postal_code` is all to one address.

Comment: Migrate works by mapping one source rows to one destination entity. You can not generate update-able sub-entities for a sub-field within a migration row. If your address field is an ER field, you could use `migration_lookup` to reference entities from a previous "city" migration. Or you could use Migrate Plus' `entity_generate`, but these entities miss all goodies from Migrate module (update, rollback,..)

Comment: Is your field_address really an entity? Or is it just a field with multiple columns (like URL field has a URI and a title column)

Comment: Ahh you are right it isn't an entity.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a custom process plugin for the address field.

```
  field_address:
    -
      plugin: myaddress
      source:
        locality: city
        administrative_area: state
        postal_code: postalcode
```

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_migration\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\ProcessPluginBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;

/**
 * Maps values for address.
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "myaddress"
 * )
 */
class MyAddress extends ProcessPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {

    $parsed = [];
    // If city name has `and` or `or` it will create multiple address items.
    $cities = preg_split("/ (or|and) /", $value[0]);
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
      $data['country_code'] = 'US';
      $data['locality'] = $city;
      $data['administrative_area'] = $value[1];
      $data['postal_code'] = $value[2];
      $parsed[] = $data;
    }

    return $parsed;
  }

}
```

My plugin checks to see if there is a string `and` or `or` and if there is it converts it multiple values.  Of course, this works out for me because all are US and the cities are for the same state.